# get the constructor's arguments from the class of object

Tags: php, class, object, reflection, constructor

Am trying to get the constructor's arguments from the class of `$object`:

```
$reflectionClass = new \ReflectionClass($object);
$constructor = $reflectionClass->getConstructor();
$constructor_params = $constructor -> getParameters();
```

The error I get:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getParameters() on a non-object
```

#### Update:

It turns out that it doesn't have a constructor. How can I check that it does first?

Comment: are you sure the class *has* a constructor?

Comment: Seems that `$constructor` isn't instance of ReflectionMethod.
Can you show us `var_dump($constructor);`?

Comment: Ugh. No it doesn't. I'll update my question

Comment: `hasMethod('__construct')` obviously

Comment: @Miraage as you can guess from my other comment, it contains `NULL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether it has a constructor with:

```
if (null !== ($constructor = $reflectionClass->getConstructor())) {
    // we have a constructor
}
```

However, that doesn't necessarily mean you can instantiate an object (e.g. when the constructor is private):

```
if ($reflectionClass->isInstantiable()) {
    // class can be instantiated with new XYZ()
}
```

Comment: Does the second one imply the first? Or does the second test go inside the first? Also, will `getParameters()` get the constructor argument values or names?

Comment: @user1644112 the second condition is independent of the first actually. And `getParameters()` [see documentation] gives an array of `ReflectionParameter`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) on `$costructor` before calling `getParameters`. If it is not set, there are no constructors.

Comment: $reflectionClass = new \ReflectionClass($object);
        if($reflectionClass->isInstantiable() && null !== ($constructor = $reflectionClass->getConstructor())) {
            $constructor_params = get_object_vars($object);
            $constructor_params = array_values( $constructor_params );
    }
        else {
            $constructor_params = array();
        }